# debug assertion failed error nptr!=NULL

Tags: c++

I get an Debug Assertion Error with expression: nptr!=NULL

my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     cout << "Hello Number " << atoi(argv[1]) << endl;
}
```

can somebody please help me solve this?

Comment: Check whether argv[1] is equal to NULL

Comment: before you use `argv` you need to check `argc`.

Comment: I suspect you forgot to pass an argument to the program.

Comment: OT: it's `int main`

Comment: thaks guys for the help, i've just solved it! stupid me didnt pass any argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely explanation is that you're not passing any parameters to your program, such as you would with the command `runme 7`.

The `argv[argc]` string is required to be `NULL` so this would explain why the assertion is happening.

Check that you have the correct number of parameters before trying to use them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cerr << "Usage: runme <integer argument>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Hello Number " << atoi(argv[1]) << endl;
}
```